# Using firewalld on a gateway certain websites are not accessible over HTTPS

Tags: iptables, firewalld

I'm building a firewall / gateway on a raspberry PI (Debian 9)

I'm using firewalld to create firewall rules.

So far, most sites and services are working fine. However there are a few sites that are not accessible, one example is Netflix. However, Facebook and Google work perfectly over HTTPS.

So I have 3 interfaces configured, lan0, ppp0, and vpn0

`lan0 = Local lan interface 192.168.1.2/24
ppp0 = PPPoE connection to my internet provider 
vpn0 = Openconnect connection to a work VPN`

Starting off with an unconfigured firewall, these are the only commands I used to set things up:

`firewall-cmd --zone=external --change-interface=ppp0
firewall-cmd --zone=external --change-interface=vpn0
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --change-interface=lan0
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http`

I then browse the internet from a local client (192.168.1.5) and most sites are working. But I'm having a problem with Netflix and Skype (so far).

Here is what happens when I used curl from the same client, it just hangs forever.

`curl -v https://www.netflix.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.netflix.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.19.56.133...
* Connected to www.netflix.com (52.19.56.133) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* SSLv3, TLS unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):`

The same command from the gateway works (RPI) just fine.

Looks like the client is stuck waiting for a server response? Did I miss something?

Comment: Does the client have openssl installed and a default set of certs created?

Answer (score 0):

After much Googling, it turns out this has nothing to do with my firewall at all.

It was all related to what MTU setting I had on my PPPoE link.

The solution was to set it to 1452.

A full explanation can be seen [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/mtu-issues.html)

Comment: Please check that your firewall rules will allow ICMP messages of type `fragmentation-needed` through. It allows a technique called [Path MTU discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) to automatically determine the optimal MTU value for each connection, and is supported by essentially all operating systems since Windows 95. If you're blocking it, you might also have problems accessing some cloud services or systems behind an IPv6 gateway, as those may restrict the MTU value still further.

Comment: re @telcoM, `firewalld` configuration as described should be OK.  It allows RELATED packets.  (And if I read correctly, *all* the pre-packaged zones explicitly allow all icmp types for input and forwarding.  Maybe I'm reading it wrong).